# DBContext not updating foreign key on update

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, dbcontext

We are migrating over from EF4 to EF5 and part of this is the move from POCO Generator created classes to the DBContext generated classes.  However, we are now seeing issues where the foreign keys are not being set on updates.

I have the following

```
    public abstract partial class Contact
    {
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
      public Nullable<int> AddressID { get; set; }

      public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class UserContact : Contact
    {
      public string Description { get; set; }
      public string Notes { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Address
    {
      public string Line1 { get; set; }
      public string Line2 { get; set; }
    }
```

If I create a contact without an address, in my first operation, then update the contact to add an address in the next operation, the AddressID in the contact is not being populated - it remains null.  So, when I do this:

```
    UserContact contact = new UserContact
    {
      FirstName = "fname",
      LastName = "lname"
    };
    int contactID = _contactAccessor.AddContact(contact); // add contact no address

    UserContact retContact = m_contactAccessor.GetContact(contactID);
    retContact.Address = new Address
    {
      Line1 = "line1",
      Line2 = "line2",          
    };        
    m_contactAccessor.UpdateContact(retrievedContact); // add an address to the contact
```

In the ContactAccessor, my UpdateContact method does this:

```
   public void UpdateContact(UserContact userContact)
   {
      UserContact retrievedContact = (from c in context.Contact.OfType<UserContact>()
                               .Include(c => c.Address)
                                where (c.ID == userContact.ID)
                                select c).FirstOrDefault());

      retrievedContact.Address = userContact.Address;
      context.Entry<Contact>(retrievedContact).CurrentValues.SetValues(userContact);
      context.SaveChanges());
    }
```

If I look at the database, the contact is created, as is the new address, but the AddressID on the contact is null, so the contact has no association with the address.
I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you regenerate the classes?